# What logical Law is this?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

p∧(~q∨s)⟺(~q∨s)∧p

What Logical law is being represented here? I think it is associative, but the q, and s should be swapped on the other end of the proposition to make that true so I'm stuck.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: It isn't. Just assumed within a community of people who have info about Computer Science someone could be helpful.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask on [cs.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called **commutativity**

```
a∧b = b∧a
```

for logical expressions a,b.